# Reading from file with array list and class

Tags: file, class, arraylist

I want to use the class `IpAddress` instead of `String` in my List, like this:

```
ArrayList<IpAddress> IpAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

But it doesn't work. I cannot add the string `line` to my list, so the program does not work as I want. What should I do?

```
public class IpAddress implements Comparable<IpAddress> {

    private String ip;

    public IpAddress(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }       

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IpAddress o) {
        return this.ip.compareTo(o.ip);
    }
}

public class IPvLIST {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("ip.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ArrayList<String> IpAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        int n = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            IpAddresses.add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs, but not good for me!
I want to use the class (IpAddress) instead of String in my List.
But of course it doesn't work, beacuse i cannot add 'line' to my list, so i am not able to use my program, like i want to.
What should i do? Please help me.

Comment: like this. ArrayList<IpAddress>IpAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Hi Viktor, can you please add your question in the question it self instead of the comments? Please take a look at our question guide: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string `line` to an IpAddress.  Based on the code you have, change the `while` statement to

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    IpAddresses.add(new IpAddress(line));
}
```

Depending if this is a simple test program or something more, you might also look into the .NET class `IPAddress`.  This has a parse function that will take the string and convert it to an `IPAddress` which makes it easier to perform actual network functions.